# What's the quickest way to navigate between the "main" and "meta" portions of GIS SE?

Tags: support, status-completed

What's the quickest way to navigate between the "main" and "meta" portions of GIS SE?

I know I can go to my profile area then scroll down to my list of SE sites then click on the right one, but it ought to be an obvious, single click of a button, surely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to make the switch each way now seems to be by using the "burger" at top right on both the Main and Meta sites:

[image]

Comment: or one can just type "meta.", before the main url address. For example: gis.stackexchange.com/users/115/polygeo to meta.gis.stackexchange.com/users/115/polygeo

Comment: or create two bookmarks in your web browser and have both up - have GIS-SE as one of four homepages on start-up of firefox.

Comment: while they may work, both of those alternatives are as "bad" as what i "had" to do before :-)